# Select all which not in related table

Tags: sqlite, go, go-gorm

for example I have the following gorm objects in tables.

```
user
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
| 1  | John |
+----+------+
| 2  | Jane |
+----+------+

phones
+----+------+
| id |number|
+----+------+
| 1  | 0945 |
+----+------+
| 2  | 0950 |
+----+------+
| 3  | 1045 |
+----+------+

user_phones
+----+-------+--------+
| id |user_id|phone_id|
+----+-------+--------+
| 1  | 1     | 1      |
+----+-------+--------+
| 2  | 1     | 2      |
+----+-------+--------+
| 3  | 2     | 3      |
+----+-------+--------+
```

With gorm I would like select all phones which not given user is.
Something like: select * phones where user_phones.user_id != 1
Thats what I tried:

```
Gdb.Order("id desc").Where("status = ?", true).Find(&phones).Related("UserPhones").Not("UserPhones.User.ID = ?", user.ID)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to work using a join rather than gorm's *related*. Perhaps not idiomatic gorm, but I never have any luck with the advanced relationships in gorm.

```
Gdb.LogMode(true)

if err := Gdb.Joins("left join user_phones on phones.id=user_phones.phone_id").Order("id desc").Where("status = ?", true).Not("user_phones.user_id = ?", user.Id).Find(&phones).Error; err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", err)
} else {
    fmt.Printf("result = %+v\n", phones)
}
```

This produces the following SQL:

```
SELECT  `phones`.* FROM `phones` left join user_phones on phones.id=user_phones.phone_id WHERE (status = 'true') AND NOT (user_phones.user_id = '1') ORDER BY id desc
```

And output:

```
result = [{Id:3 Number:1045}]
```

I used mysql as that's what I'm used to, but I can't see sqlite being any different.

Comment: Many thanks for that, but i got nothing as result, but needed phones entry with id 3.

Comment: I've updated my answer with logging / error checking - can you try again?

Comment: Ahh I needed some more where .Where("user_phones.id is null"). :)